# Bash Error: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm newbie to Ubuntu, I've just started using it, previously when I used cd command to change directory it was working fine but now I'm trying to change the directory using cd command but I'm getting this error on terminal **No such file or directory**.

I've tried commands shown in screenshot but it doesn't work for me.

[image]

Could you please help me to resolve that one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu is case sensitive. You should be using `cd Workspace` as the correct command. Does that work for you?

Comment: Hi Java, welcome to the site! Please next time post the copied output instead of an image. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a capital W in the name of your directory. Linux is case sensitive.